# Config key not found : Where does typesafe ConfigFactory.load look for config files in a scala multi-project?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, multi-project

When I run sbt test on the complete multi-project, I keep getting config key not found when it is clearly there in the resource folder corresponding to the test. Everything works fine when I run the tests with intellij.

I followed this to setup the project : https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html

The following is the structure :

root(main project)
- util
- api(depends on util)
- consumer(depends on util)

1. There are no tests in root project. All its config is in 'main' folder resources.
2. 'api' and 'consumer' modules have their own tests and their own resources containing config files.
3. Some of these tests have objects which needs to read config and are not able to find them.

Comment: Can you add more infos, like do you use a cross-project plugin, is it a pure JVM multi-project, how do you run the tests in intellij.

Answer (score 1):

It will first look into the module from where you are running the test and there is finding conf which doesn't contains your config key. When you run from intellij that time you are in same module so it can pick the configuration. You can provide the path of the configuration file while loading the configuration and it can solve your problem.